# Swift : Using multiple swift files or not with only one viewController? Keeping it clean

Tags: swift, refactoring, viewcontroller

I'm pretty new in programming in swift. Right now I'm halfway through a course and really loving it. Right now I'm a musician and before I started this course, I already had an idea of what app to make. So I started making this Music Play along app and am pretty happy already with how it's coming together. On to my question :

I've been coding all of my functions, variables and outlets into the main ViewController.swift file. It's becoming a pretty long read and I was thinking if it would be better to separate some functions in different swift files. Now as I understand it, different .swift files come into play if you create classes that aren't directly related to each other, but so far all of my code is related to this single ViewController aka the main screen. Disregarding the efficiency that probably could be better in my coding, should I keep on going in this single file, or should I start differentiating some parts of my code and put them in their own swift files?

Alright thanks in advance and also, thank you SO much for all the invaluable information on this website. This is a pretty amazing community. 
-Patrick

Comment: Are you sure your code can't be broken down into multiple classes? Read up on the MVC pattern and make sure you separate your Models, Views and Controllers. "different .swift files come into play if you create classes that aren't directly related to each other" That's not true. Things in different Swift files _can_ refer to each other.

Comment: I see! Thanks I will try to organize it with the MVC pattern. It was mentioned and explained in the course, but never really how to put it into practice regarding organization. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I structure my code like this: the ViewController is divided into 3 files, in the first there is the declaration and also the override methods and obj-C methods, in the second file I put the delegate, on extension for each delegate and in the first there is a unique extension where I put all the helper methods.
If the application contains only one ViewController  you can leave all inside the main, but if the app will be a more complicated and structured, it's better you create a second viewController presented by the parent ViewController where you perform all what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks Andrea for sharing!